# Communicating between Android and PC (C#)

Tags: c#, android

I want to create an application in Android which communicates with a server application (written in C#, doesn't matter what version of .NET) on the PC via TCP/IP.
What would be the best approach here?

I was thinking about some kind of RPC-like SOAP or XML-RPC. But I want to keep the server application as light and simple as possible. And I think in C# you rely on a Webserver to set up an RPC server. Is it better to communicate directly via the TcpListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had pretty good luck using TCP/IP and UDP with android and windows (Java & C# respectively).  I used a more brutal approach then the TCPListener for the C# but pretty similar at the high level.  I would recommend giving it a shot and seeing the outcome, chances are it's going to be fairly more lightweight in terms of processing and bandwidth then an XML approach.

Comment: It might, indeed be better for now, to just use a higher level.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data will your program be sending over the network?  If it's something simple why not use a high level protocol like http?  I'm more of a java person, but I know that there must be a .net equivalent to running a lean http server to connect to.

Comment: For now it will be rather simple data. However, in the future it might need to transfer more complex data.